# Efficient algorithm to find an vertex that is not an articulation vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

This is a question from the book The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena, Page no- 201.

**Articulation vertex** : An articulation vertex of a graph (undirected) G is a vertex whose deletion disconnects G.

**Given**  : Graph (undirected) $G = (V,E)$

**Find** : A vertex not an articulation vertex

Here is how i tried. I know a brute force way to solve the problem. A1 is the brute force algorithm given below.

**Algorithm A1**

1. Pick a vertex say $v$.
2. Delete the vertex temporarily from $G$ (say $G'$ is a new graph).
3. Run DFS on $G'$.
4. If graph $G'$ is **connected** return (V).
5. Else repeat (step 1 to step 4) for all vertice of $G$.

**Runtime** : $O(V(V + E))$

For better running time algorithm i tried to come up with a claim.

**My Claim** : A vertex is an not articulation vertex if in a DFS tree it involves in a back edge.

If the above claim is true then i only need to run the DFS algorithm once that means running time $O(V + E)$.
So I have two questions 1) Is the claim correct 2) find an efficient algorithm which runs in $O(V + E)$. time.

Comment: What do you mean with the word "involves"?

Comment: Yes but previously i assume that node u is not a root node of DFS tree

Comment: @sameerkn Normally, yes. Unless there's some context that implies that a different meaning is intended.

Comment: @sameerkn i have given an algorithm of same time complexity in the questio  n .if you know an efficient algorithm please write in answer.

Comment: [Tarjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Linear_time_depth_first_search)'s algorithms grows a DFS tree. A node is not an articulation point iff it has a back edge from a *subtree* to a node above. Special rule for the root.